# Permission denied on start-dfs.sh

Tags: networking, virtualbox, password, ip, hadoop

I am trying to create a 2-node Hadoop cluster, following this [guide](https://chawlasumit.wordpress.com/2015/03/09/install-a-multi-node-hadoop-cluster-on-ubuntu-14-04/). The one node is my Ubuntu laptop and the slave node, the 2nd one, is a virtualbox that also runs Ubuntu.

I am doing in the **master** node:

```
gsamaras@gsamaras:/home/hadoopuser/hadoop/sbin$ sudo ./start-dfs.sh
16/01/23 04:46:16 WARN hdfs.DFSUtil: Namenode for null remains unresolved for ID null.  Check your hdfs-site.xml file to ensure namenodes are configured properly.
Starting namenodes on [master]
master: ssh: Could not resolve hostname master: Name or service not known
root@localhost's password: 
root@localhost's password: localhost: Permission denied, please try again.
```

If now I edit my `/etc/hosts/` file to this:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.1.1   gsamaras
127.0.1.1   slave-1
127.0.1.1   master   // should I have this?
```

the warning will leave, but I will still get a "permission denied". This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28419730/hadoop2-6-0-sudo-sbin-start-dfs-sh-fail) is exactly the same with mine's, but the answer did not help much. Any ideas *please*?

Comment: Do `sudo bash start-dfs.sh`.

Comment: Same behavior @Raphael

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to give permission to your script file:

```
$ sudo chmod +x start-dfs.sh
```

Then execute.

```
$ sudo bash start-dfs.sh
```

Comment: What about `/etc/hosts/`, how should I have it? I am getting a `sudo: +x: command not found`. I asked a question about it here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/724681/sudo-x-command-not-found

Comment: That worked `sudo chmod +x start-dfs.sh`, but I am getting the same result, permission denied.

Comment: Solution: Go to `sshd_config`, change `PermitRootLogin without-password -> PermitRootLogin yes` and do an ssh restart.

Answer (score 2):

I am able to resolve the issue using below commands.

The following commands are used for generating a key value pair using SSH. Copy the public keys form id_rsa.pub to authorized_keys, and provide the owner with read and write permissions to authorized_keys file respectively.

```
$ ssh-keygen -t rsa 
$ cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys 
$ chmod 0600 ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
```