# Starting Hadoop file system with `start-dfs.sh` permission denied

Tags: permissions, hadoop

I try to install hbase one a standalone node but I have some issue to launch Hadoop file system with `start-dfs.sh` :

```
mike@mike-thinks:/usr/local/hadoop/sbin$ ./start-dfs.sh 
Incorrect configuration: namenode address dfs.namenode.servicerpc-address or dfs.namenode.rpc-address is not configured.
Starting namenodes on []
./start-dfs.sh: line 61: /usr/local/hadoop/sbin/hadoop-daemons.sh: Permission denied
./start-dfs.sh: line 74: /usr/local/hadoop/sbin/hadoop-daemons.sh: Permission denied
Starting secondary namenodes [0.0.0.0]
./start-dfs.sh: line 87: /usr/local/hadoop/sbin/hadoop-daemons.sh: Permission denied
```

And with sudo :

```
mike@mike-thinks:/usr/local/hadoop/sbin$ sudo ./start-dfs.sh 
[sudo] password for mike: 
Incorrect configuration: namenode address dfs.namenode.servicerpc-address or dfs.namenode.rpc-address is not configured.
Starting namenodes on []
./start-dfs.sh: line 61: /usr/local/hadoop/sbin/hadoop-daemons.sh: Permission denied
./start-dfs.sh: line 74: /usr/local/hadoop/sbin/hadoop-daemons.sh: Permission denied
Starting secondary namenodes [0.0.0.0]
./start-dfs.sh: line 87: /usr/local/hadoop/sbin/hadoop-daemons.sh: Permission denied
```

So I did `sudo chmod +x /usr/local/hadoop/sbin/`

```
mike@mike-thinks:/usr/local/hadoop/sbin$ sudo chmod +x /usr/local/hadoop/sbin/
[sudo] password for mike: 
mike@mike-thinks:/usr/local/hadoop/sbin$ ./start-dfs.sh 
Incorrect configuration: namenode address dfs.namenode.servicerpc-address or dfs.namenode.rpc-address is not configured.
Starting namenodes on []
./start-dfs.sh: line 61: /usr/local/hadoop/sbin/hadoop-daemons.sh: Permission denied
./start-dfs.sh: line 74: /usr/local/hadoop/sbin/hadoop-daemons.sh: Permission denied
Starting secondary namenodes [0.0.0.0]
./start-dfs.sh: line 87: /usr/local/hadoop/sbin/hadoop-daemons.sh: Permission denied
```

I have yet to try to go to sshd_config, change PermitRootLogin without-password -> PermitRootLogin yes and do an ssh restart as gsamaras suggests in [a related question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/724523/permission-denied-on-start-dfs-sh) but it seems so unlikely to be linked.

---

I did a `chmod +x *.sh` and it solved the issue. And I now have a `Incorrect configuration`error :

```
mike@mike-thinks:/usr/local/hadoop/sbin$ ./start-dfs.sh 
Incorrect configuration: namenode address dfs.namenode.servicerpc-address or dfs.namenode.rpc-address is not configured.
Starting namenodes on []
localhost: mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/usr/local/hadoop/logs’: Permission denied
localhost: chown: cannot access '/usr/local/hadoop/logs': No such file or directory
localhost: starting namenode, logging to /usr/local/hadoop/logs/hadoop-mike-namenode-mike-thinks.out
localhost: /usr/local/hadoop/sbin/hadoop-daemon.sh: line 159: /usr/local/hadoop/logs/hadoop-mike-namenode-mike-thinks.out: No such file or directory
localhost: head: cannot open '/usr/local/hadoop/logs/hadoop-mike-namenode-mike-thinks.out' for reading: No such file or directory
localhost: /usr/local/hadoop/sbin/hadoop-daemon.sh: line 177: /usr/local/hadoop/logs/hadoop-mike-namenode-mike-thinks.out: No such file or directory
localhost: /usr/local/hadoop/sbin/hadoop-daemon.sh: line 178: /usr/local/hadoop/logs/hadoop-mike-namenode-mike-thinks.out: No such file or directory
localhost: mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/usr/local/hadoop/logs’: Permission denied
localhost: chown: cannot access '/usr/local/hadoop/logs': No such file or directory
localhost: starting datanode, logging to /usr/local/hadoop/logs/hadoop-mike-datanode-mike-thinks.out
localhost: /usr/local/hadoop/sbin/hadoop-daemon.sh: line 159: /usr/local/hadoop/logs/hadoop-mike-datanode-mike-thinks.out: No such file or directory
localhost: head: cannot open '/usr/local/hadoop/logs/hadoop-mike-datanode-mike-thinks.out' for reading: No such file or directory
localhost: /usr/local/hadoop/sbin/hadoop-daemon.sh: line 177: /usr/local/hadoop/logs/hadoop-mike-datanode-mike-thinks.out: No such file or directory
localhost: /usr/local/hadoop/sbin/hadoop-daemon.sh: line 178: /usr/local/hadoop/logs/hadoop-mike-datanode-mike-thinks.out: No such file or directory
Starting secondary namenodes [0.0.0.0]
The authenticity of host '0.0.0.0 (0.0.0.0)' can't be established.
ECDSA key fingerprint is SHA256:/s7X8QMliB6FVx5bde5AaCycprQ/B+NtcTXrInrXxJM.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? no
0.0.0.0: Host key verification failed.
```

Comment: Did you check for execute permission - exactly like your previous question [hdfs: command not found with Hadoop2.9.0](https://askubuntu.com/questions/983175/hdfs-command-not-found-with-hadoop2-9-0)

Comment: @steeldriver like `sudo chown -R` ? Not yet I'm thinking about what to write then

Comment: @steeldriver I think I've understood I did `sudo chmod +x /usr/local/hadoop/sbin/` but the errors remain

Comment: You probably need to change permissions on the **file** `/usr/local/hadoop/sbin/hadoop-daemons.sh` not the **directory** `/usr/local/hadoop/sbin/`

Answer (score 0):

```
# Create the .ssh directory:
$ mkdir ~/.ssh

# Set the right permissions:
$ chmod 700 ~/.ssh

# Create the authorized_keys file:
$ touch ~/.ssh/authorized_keys

# Set the right permissions:
$ chmod 600 ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

The permissions are important! It won't work without the right permissions!

Now you can add the public key to the `authorized_keys` file:

```
$ cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

And finally you can execute:

```
$ ./start-dfs.sh
```